# Pointwise convergence of this function

Tags: limits, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

Suppose that for every positive integer $n$, we have a function $f_n(x)$ such that $∀ x ∈ {1, 1/2, . . . , 1/n}, f_n(x) = x$ and at all other real numbers $x, f_n(x) = 0$. Find the [pointwise limit function $f$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_convergence) of $(f_n)$ on $R$.

As $n$ tends to infinity, the interval on which $f_n(x)$ is non-zero becomes smaller and smaller (as  $1/n$ $\rightarrow$ $0$). So does this mean that the point-wise limit is $0$?

Comment: For instance, $f_n(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n\geq 2$. So we must have $f(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$, so it can't be the zero function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $ q $ be an integer $\ge 1 $.
Then

$$n\ge q \implies \frac 1q\in\{1,\frac 12,\cdots, \frac 1n\}$$
thus
$$n\ge q\implies f_n(\frac 1q)=\frac 1q$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(\frac 1q)=\frac 1q$$

Comment: But $f_n(1)=1$ for all $n$, so the limit can't possibly be $0$

Comment: Going off what OP wrote, for $n=100$ we have $\forall x\in\{1,1/2,1/3,\dots,1/100\}$ that $f_{100}(x)=x$. Hence $f_{100}(1)=1$...

Comment: @jlammy Yes, you're right. I edited.

Comment: This makes sense. So, if $N$ is any natural number, n greater than or equal to N implies $f_n(x)$ tends to x. So the point wise limit would be f(x) = x. Thank you!

Comment: @SC No, the limit function is not identity. $ f(\pi)=0$ for example.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes! So f(x)=x when x = 1/q, where q is an integer greater than or equal to 1, and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: @SC Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$